Get error "You do not have elevated access" when try to postpone MFA enforcement
I have a small dev Azure Subscription.
When I login to Azure Portal, I get this page:

This is a small dev Azure subscription and I don't have time to deal with this. In addition I am not able to find a meaningful documentation or Youtube video how to quickly eliminate the message.
I like to postpone the enforcement, but when I click on Postpone, I get this message:

How can I get elevated access?

The error occurs if you miss enabling elevated access which is mandatory to postpone MFA enforcement.
To get elevated access, sign in to Azure Portal with user having Global Administrator role and turn on below option:
Go to Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra ID -> Properties -> Access Management for Azure resources -> Yes -> Save

Enabling above option will assign "User Access Administrator" role to the user at root scope (/)  which elevates the access. You need to sign out and sign back in to refresh the access.
Now, try to postpone the MFA enforcement again which won't throw "You do not have elevated access" error.
Reference:
Azure Mandatory MFA Planning Guide – Boost Security by CHARBEL NEMNOM

It helps.. Thanks
